# eclipse kepler "Cannot install remote marketplace locations"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-marketplace

I have downloaded the latest eclipse version, eclipse kepler.

But when i try to access the Marketplace inside eclipse or try to install ADT plugin for Android, it gives me this creepy error which is driving me crazy:

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
Connection reset
Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Connection reset
```

Comment: Strange, I have never seen anything like this. The new Android Studio.. give it a try...

Comment: I need to get eclipse working, dont want to use the Android Studio

Comment: i think i found out the problem

Comment: i posted the answer :)

Comment: I have the same problem, having NO android. On the contrary, Spring Tools eclipse it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out finally that:

Avira Anti-Virus Software was blocking the network requests by eclipse. 
After deactivating "enable web protection" in the Anti-Virus, 
the stupid Eclipse was able to update itself.

Comment: Sorry, It is not the problem. Yesterday the marketplace worked for me OK, and the settings of AVG remain unchanged.

Comment: And stopping the on-line shield won't help even after Eclipse restart

Comment: This one worked for me, some how after one day (maybe an update from my AV) marketplace was blocked. thanks for Sharing

Comment: Had the same problem, deactivated avast agents for 10 minutes worked fine

Comment: This worked for me, I was using avast but same problem

Answer (score 11):

please put below line to eclipse.ini in the last it worked for me
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Answer (score 2):

If you are sitting behind a corporate network it could be filtering out requests coming from eclipse. Switching to 3G on my phone made it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This frustrated me for a while before I stumbled upon this link:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/783720/

It says clear SOCKS entry in Network connections and be in manual Active Provider.

The SOCKS entry was already clear but after clicking on clear again, it just worked so worth a shot.